# iOS: method returns a block then the block is stored in array, when should I copy it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that returns a block and another method which uses the method:

```
- (MyBlock)blockForParameter:(id)param
{
    MyBlock theBlock = ^(){NSLog(@"Param: %@", param);};
    return theBlock;
}

- (void)methodUser
{
    MyBlock theBlock = [self blockForParameter:something];
    [self.allBlocks addObject:theBlock];
}
```

The question is, when should I copy the block? Should I copy the block when I return it in `blockForParameter`, or should I copy it when I add it to the array?

Thanks

Comment: do you even need to copy it in this case? a new `MyBlock` is being created each time you call that function isnt it? I'm no expert with blocks but thats what i think would be happening..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks must be copied if they "outlive the scope in which they were created", so you must copy the block in your `blockForParameter` method, before returning it.

*Edit:* With ARC, this is no longer true. See for example [Objective-C: blocks in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643456/objective-c-blocks-in-arc) and the references therein:

- Returning a block from a function does not require to copy the block.
- Adding a block to a collection *does require* a block copy.

Comment: afaik, when returning an object that was created in a scope that was returned to another function it will keep that object alive even once its original scope has finished... or are blocks some sort of special case?

Comment: @Fonix: Blocks are a bit special, as they are created on the stack and must be moved to the heap if they outlive the scope of their creation.

Comment: In the case of ARC, isn't it the same if I copy it when return and not copy it when adding to a collection?

Comment: @hzxu: Actually, in your case you *need* not copy the block at all. The function returns a copy of the block and that can safely be added to the array. But I would just stick to the rules, copying a block twice does not make a difference.

Comment: With ARC, ARC just copies it for you in some cases. So it is still true that the blocks must be copied.

Comment: Why the downvote? Both statements are from the Transitioning to ARC Release Notes. What is wrong in the answer?

Comment: @MartinR I did not down vote, and I just got another question, if you copy it twice in ARC, does ARC know to release it twice?

Comment: @hzxu: Blocks are objects, so they are released and deallocated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Look at each method separately.

In `-blockForParameter:`, the block literal is returned from the method. The block must be copied in order to outlive the scope of the literal. In MRC, you would need to return the block copied and autoreleased. In ARC, you don't need to do anything.

In `-methodUser`, the block is not defined in that method; it is received from a method call. Thus, it must have already been copied (i.e. it is not a stack block). Thus, you do not need to do anything with it when you do `addObject:` to it.